# Matching 15 or 16 digit number in Regex with spaces or -'s between numbers

Tags: regex, xml, exchange-server

I've been trying to create a regex query to match numbers

What I'm trying to match is a 15 or 16 digit number, between each number there can be `0` or more spaces, or `-`'s. I don't want to match a number in the middle of a string, and I don't want to match a number between multiple lines. From reading around, I'm sure my current implementation can be simplified a lot.

```
^(\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d[ -]*\d\d?\s*)$
```

With this expression I'm hoping to match any 15 or 16 digit number (And only 15 or 16 digits), with any number of spaces and/or `-`'s between each number.

So for instance

```
123456789123456
1234567891234567
1  23  4  5678--9-1----234--5 -  6
```

Here's the bit which I'm finding tricky. This regex will be used in an Exchange DLP template, which uses XML. It'll be parsing each email and alerting on any matches. Using regexr as a site to validate my regex, I've found the above query  will match the number if it's the only thing in the text filed, but otherwise will not. If I enable the `\m` flag at the end, it'll match everything correctly. But when adding the `\m` flag in the DLP template, the rule matches nothing

for instance the following should NOT match

```
1.  /123456789123456/
2.  123456 

   123456789
3. sample1234567891234567text
```

The number wont neccessarily be on it's own line, and could be contained in a phrase like

```
'Here's your number: 123456789123456'
'Here's your number:123456789123456'
```

Comment: Also, can't you simplify your expression to something like this: `(\d[ -]*){15,16}`?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, very new to regex - knew there'd be a simpler way of detecting the numbers!

Comment: The core of what you need is `(?:^|\r?\n)\d(?:[ -]*\d){14,15}|\d(?:[ -]*\d){14,15}(?:$|\r?\n)`. But you have other possible edge conditions, such as leading/trailing `[ -]` and probably most important, since you require 15-16 digits, you'd have to validate that with `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` respectively. That validation can be done without assertions, but it makes the regex bigger. And I'm guessing you haven't thought about that yet, so no need posting an answer.

Comment: hmm thank you. I'll play around with it tomorrow. By assertions you're referring to the lookbehind and negative lookahead right? Is there any reason to avoid these, other than possibility that the implementation of regex I'll be using wont support them?

Comment: I'm just guessing if the engine doesn't support multi-line mode, it probably doesn't support assertions. Otherwise, the full edge case spectrum including assertions could be something like `(?:^|\r?\n)[ -]*(\d(?:[ -]*\d){14,15})[ -]*(?![\d -])|(?<![\d -])[ -]*(\d(?:[ -]*\d){14,15})[ -]*(?:$|\r?\n)` where capture group 1 contains trimmed number if at the beginning, likewise group 2 at the end. And, these assertions can be simulated, making this an even bigger (small monster) regex.

Answer (score 0):

something like this: `(?:\d[ \-]*){15,16}`
meaning that there could be 15 to 16 groups of *digit followed by any number of spaces or dashes*.

also if you need to include spaces and dashes before the first digit, you should add the check before groups:

`^[ \-]*(?:\d[ \-]*){15,16}$`

or if you need to find that numbers in a larger text (excluding larger numbers):

`(?<=[^\d \-])[ \-]*(?:\d[ \-]*){15,16}(?=[^\d \-])`

or the same with negative lookaround:

`(?<![\d \-])[ \-]*(?:\d[ \-]*){15,16}(?![\d \-])`

Comment: Though with this, wont it detect 16 digits within a larger number? That's why  I've been putting the ^ and $ to match the start and end of the number.

Comment: What site do you recommend to check regex? regex101 isn't detecting any matches with your latest regex

Comment: i would recommend using the exact regex engine used by your technology. If it has repl, check it in repl, otherwise just create unit test for that.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Going to sleep on this and have another look tomorrow, Definitely gotten much further than I was previously with yours and everyone elses help! Thanks for your patience in explaining and answering my questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
([0-9- ]{15,16})
[0-9- ] // match numbers 0-9, space and dash
{15,16} // 15 to 16 chars
```

https://regex101.com/r/hX3vR6/1

Comment: this is wrong, since for example `----  1 ----    ` would be matched

Comment: @leetwinski `With this expression I'm hoping to match any 15 or 16 digit number (And only 15 or 16 digits), with any number of spaces and/or -'s between each number.` is in the question, I don't know why this should not be matched?

Comment: the question is literraly about 15 to 16 *digits* number, possibly separated with spaces or dashes. So your solution doesn't guarantee 16 *digits*, rather it guarantees 16 characters of *digit-space-or-dash*

Comment: As leetwinski has mentioned, the spaces and dashes should not be counted within the 16 characters.

Answer (score 0):

To match the examples you provided, and not match the *negative* examples I suggest:

```
(?<=(\W|^))(?:\d[ -]*){15,16}(?=(\W|$))
```

It uses lookbehind/lookahead to check the number not to be followed/preceded by a word-character.

Comment: Thanks, nice to see everyone has a slightly different way of doing this. I'll test it out tomorrow and see what results I get.  :)